# Why do I get this error message when debugging my ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-debugging

I'm developing an ASP.NET app using Visual Studio Professional 2019. I use Microsoft Edge as my browser.

When I start my app without debugging (<kbd>Ctrl + F5</kbd>), everything works fine.

When I start my app with debugging (<kbd>F5</kbd>), I get this error message :

> Hmmm… can't reach this page
>
> It looks like the webpage at file:///C:/%5CProgramData%5CMicrosoft%5CVisualStudio%5CEdgeAdapter%5C94d888de/landingPage.html might be having issues, or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

It is really weird, because %5C is the equivalent of a backslash. And when replacing all the %5C with "\", I can see that the page indeed exists.

Looking into IIS (version 10), I have fiddled around and tried being smart: I changed the value of "Enable 32-bit Applications" of my AppPool to "True", but this doesn't change anything.

As debugging in Visual Studio start IIS Express, I'm not sure modifying anything in IIS would have any effect...

Help, please !

Comment: Hi, do you encounter this issue in other browsers? Do you encounter this issue if you open this page in Edge?

Comment: Thank you PenGe. No, I don't use any other browser. You see, when I try to debug, IIS Express tries to show a landing page, but the name of this page is wrong : it is full of strange characters. So it can't be displayed.

Comment: Is your Edge version up to date? Could you share the steps or sample program to reproduce the issue?